# How does the Leetcode compiler work when executing input for a class with multiple methods?

Tags: python, class, methods

This is a question about how `Leetcode compiler` works when `executing classes and methods`.

So I am answering the following question: https://leetcode.com/contest/weekly-contest-248/problems/count-good-numbers/ (but the question is not important)

I have some code below, where I have two methods, `primeNumber(self, n)` and `countGoodNumbers(self,n)`, within the `class Solution()`.

Now, say for `input n=1`, does the compiler execute both methods (and exit once I return a value for the first method?), or how does it work? Because when I program in `Pycharm IDE`, usually at the end I would manually execute the methods I want, for example I would do `x = Solution` then `print(x.countGoodNumbers(100)`.

Or, am I correct in understanding that if I define the methods like this: `primeNumber(self, n)` and `countGoodNumbers(self,f)`, so that the compiler knows to call the first function, since the `input is "n"`?

```
class Solution:
    primes = []
    def primeNumber(self,n):
        numbers = set(range(n, 1, -1))
        self.primes = []
        while numbers:
            p = numbers.pop()
            self.primes.append(p)
            numbers.difference_update(set(range(p * 2, n + 1, p)))
        return self.primes
    
    def countGoodNumbers(self,n: int):
        counter = 0
        for i in range(int("9" * n) + 1):
            tracker = False
            i = str(i)
    
            while len(i) < n:
                i = "0" + i
            # checking odd and even digits
            for j in range(int("9" * n) + 1):
                if j == 0 or j % 2 == 0:
                    if int(i) % 2 == 0:
                        tracker = True
                    else:
                        tracker = False
                        break
                else:
                    if int(i) in self.primes:
                        tracker = True
                    else:
                        tracker = False
                        break
    
            if tracker == True:
                counter += 1
            else:
                pass
        
        return counter
```

Comment: Every "solution" executes a pre-configured method so the main logic must be implemented in that pre-loaded method. *That* method can call whatever else it wants

Comment: it is just `x = Solution(), answer = x.countGoodNumbers(n)` and then compare this answer to already known answer. since it is live contest i wont give answer, but calculate all no will be quite large and take too much time. all you need is to do  is work on even and odd indices and calucating solution based on that for eg for 1 digit no, ie at index 0 even are allowd so 5 no satisfy condition, so 5 anser same for 2 digit no 5*4 and so on